# (3* - *p/(*q)+7) = 6 how it works?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int i=3,j=5;
    int *p, *q;
    p = &i;
    q = &j;

    printf("%d\n", 3* -*p/(*q)+7);
```

The compiler says the result is 6, but i can't understand how, for me it was suposed to be (-9/12) = -0,74 or 0 beacause is a int, can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking into account the precedence rules that are implicitly encoded in [the grammar of the C language](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#A.2.1), `3* -*p/(*q)+7` is `((3 * (-*p)) / (*q)) + 7`.

The result of `-9 / 5` is `-1` because `/` represents integer division here.

The result of `-1 + 7` is 6.

Answer (score 3):

Because of [operator precedence and associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)
`3* -*p/(*q)+7` is the same as
`(3 * - 3)/5 + 7` which is the same as
`-9/5 + 7` which because of integer division is the same as
`-1 + 7` which is the same as

```
6
```